# How to format isoDateTime to dd/m/yyyy

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this time `"2012-03-23 00:00:00"`. How can I format it to `"dd/m/yyyy"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this:

```
var str="2012-03-23 00:00:00";

function convert(a){
    a=a.split(' ')[0].split('-');
    var ret=[];
    for(var i=a.length;0<=--i;){
        ret.push(1===i?parseInt(a[i],10):a[i])
    }
    return ret.join('/');
}

alert(convert(str));
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ehaCv/

Answer (score 1):

Try looking into [Datejs](http://www.datejs.com). It's a very easy-to-use library. Conversion can be seen in the [documents section](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/APIDocumentation).

Comment: Since the author has abandoned the project, I recommend downloading the community fork ([https://github.com/eric/Datejs](https://github.com/eric/Datejs)).

Answer (score 0):

new Date().toJSON() will give you:

```
"2013-03-05T18:01:21.784Z"
```